# Save data from Textbox and persist in the next session

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I would like to save some data from a `TextBox`. This information is entered by a user.

In my `Form_Load` event handler I set `Button1.Enabled = False` and have user input `right_serial_code` into `TextBox1`. If the code is correct, `Button1` is enabled.

If users puts the correct serial code, it should be persisted in the next session. So that next time the program starts, user does not need to re-enter.

Comment: You didn't ask a question. Is there a problem with what you're trying to do, or do you not know how to do it? Please add sample code showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your project properties page and open the "Settings" tab.  Create a new setting called `SerialCode`.  Set the `Type` to `String` and set the `Scope` to either `User` (so each OS user saves their own serial code) or `Application` (so all users on the machine share the same serial code).

Then, in the `Form_Load` event handler, do something like this:

```
TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.SerialCode
```

And then in the `Button1_Click` event handler, so something like this:

```
My.Settings.SerialCode = TextBox1.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

To recall any piece of information from one program run to another, you need to save it some form of persistent storage.

If the data is small and relevant to the application only, you can save it in the application configuration file.  This is an xml file associated with .net applications.  See the answer at [How can I read/write app.config settings at runtime without using user settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638754/how-can-i-read-write-app-config-settings-at-runtime-without-using-user-settings) for instructions on how to save the information.  And a more indepth article at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14744/Read-Write-App-Config-File-with-NET-2-0.