# .Net Standard (Not Core) Per Environment Configuration

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently converting a .Net Framework class library to a .Net Standard class library.  In Framework we used app.config and had transform files to hold the environment specific data such as connection strings for the environment (Prod, Test, Dev).

I have scoured SO and Google for this answer but keep coming up empty.  What is the best way to store and retrieve this data in a .Net Standard class library?  At this point I don't care if I have a bit of code that populates properties based on my Build Settings or if I have a file sitting next to the DLL that houses this data.  I'm just needing a way to connect to ServerA in dev and ServerB in prod.

I'll have either a .Net Core or .Net Framework project that references this DLL and asks this DLL for data but I want this library to house it's own DB connection, not passing it from the hundreds of apps calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager) was added back in .NETStandard 2.0.

Just pull it in from nuget and compile the **.NETStandard 2.0** class library project.

Then, the library will work across projects using standard config files:

- Net Core 2.0 projects use app.config
- Web projects work from web.config
- Console and Windows apps work with app.config

(This is of course assuming you're going to .NET Standard 2.0)

Then, [here's a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232695/how-to-use-configurationmanager) I found that discusses how to use ConfigurationManager in case you need some examples.

Comment: I thought from the articles I've found that the .config files aren't supposed to be used in .Net Standard.