# Change App.Config file at Runtime Not Worked for users without Administrator rights

Tags: c#, app-config

I change my connection String in app.config at runtime. It worked perfectly for users with Administrator rights But it is Not worked for users without Administrator Rights.

There is any way to handle this problem.
My code for changing the app.config file is.

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
                    config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["main"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=UrgentSIMDelivery;Integrated Security=true";
                    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
                    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exePath = Path.Combine( exePath, "MyApp.exe" );
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration( exePath );
    var setting = config.AppSettings.Settings[SettingKey];
    if (setting != null)
    {
        setting.Value = newValue;
    }
    else
    {
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add( SettingKey, newValue);
    }

    config.Save();
```

Source
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3678953/3156647