# How to read an appSettings key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

According to http://blog.jsinh.in/asp-net-5-configuration-microsoft-framework-configurationmodel/, things have changed.  However, I couldn't understand from that document how to read `appSettings` keys. There's an example on reading from ini files though.

How do I avoid using the old `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` to read `AppSettings` key values from web.config?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read/write app.config settings at runtime without using user settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638754/how-can-i-read-write-app-config-settings-at-runtime-without-using-user-settings)

Answer (score 7):

Add a `json` file to your project root dir: `config.json`

```
{
   "AppSettings": {
       "TestKey" :  "TestValue"
    }
}
```

Create a new `class` for config deserialization:

```
public class AppSettings
{
     public string TestKey { get; set; }
}
```

In `Startup.cs`:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
      // Setup configuration sources.
      var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
                .AddJsonFile("config.json")
                .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
      Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        var builder = services.AddMvc();

       services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
}
```

Get the options in your `controller`:

```
public HomeController(IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
{
    var value = settings.Value.TestKey;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's wrong with `System.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` [[MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx) as it still works in 4.5 & 4.6

But I think what you're asking for is `System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader.GetValue()`  [[MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingsreader.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Under `References`, I added `System.Configuration (1.0.0)` to DNX 4.5.1. However, I still get "The type or namespace 'Configuration' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly or reference?)"

Answer (score 0):

You can get values using ["setting-key"] syntax:

```
IConfiguration _configuration;
...
var setting = _configuration["SomeKey"];
```

Or you can parse config section to some custom object as follows:

```
IConfiguration configuration;
...
var myCustomObject = configuration.GetSection("SomeSection").Get<MyCustomObject>();
```

Pay attention - in second approach you should reference the following MS Nugget packages:

1. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
2. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Builder
3. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json