# Reading an app setting value from the config file

Tags: c#, app-config

In my solution I have 4 projects named UI,Business,Data and common.In the Data project I have an app.config file with following values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
 <appSettings>
 <add key="LibrarySystemConnection" value="server=(local);Initial Catalog=SanasaLibrarySystem;Integrated Security=True;
     User ID=sa;Password=123"/>
 </appSettings>
 </configuration>
```

In a class of the Data project I am accessing the above key as follows:

```
connectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["LibrarySystemConnection"];
```

When I run the code the connectionString retuns null.Anybody have an idea what is the wrong in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the `app.config` file to your primary UI project.

Comment: What I want to do is reading the connection string from a config file rather than hard coded in the Data project.

Comment: Yes, move the config file to your UI project and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Either move the app.config file to the project which generates exe or read the config from the assembley using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682054/how-do-i-retrieve-appsettings-from-the-assembly-config-file)